# подвисает главный поток при запросе Vk

Tags: java, android, vkontakte-api

Пытаюсь делать запросы к Вконтакте и выводить список в `ListFragment`(получение разных списков музыки: моя музыка, популярное, рекомендуемое и т.д). Для запросов решил сделать отдельный класс `VKRequestHelper` (даже не знаю верная ли это практика, показалось что так будет удобней).При выполнении ассинхроного `executeWithListener` приложение вылетает:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.jeka.vkplayer, PID: 3341
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=android:fragment:0, request=10485, result=-1, data=null} to activity {com.example.jeka.vkplayer/com.example.jeka.vkplayer.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference
at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3574)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3617)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:151)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1352)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference
at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getCount(ArrayAdapter.java:330)
at android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:487)
at android.app.ListFragment.setListAdapter(ListFragment.java:240)
at com.example.jeka.vkplayer.fragments.MainListFragment$1.onResult(MainListFragment.java:44)
at com.example.jeka.vkplayer.fragments.MainListFragment$1.onResult(MainListFragment.java:41)
at com.vk.sdk.VKSdk.onActivityResult(VKSdk.java:261)
at com.example.jeka.vkplayer.fragments.MainListFragment.onActivityResult(MainListFragment.java:41)
at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6196)
at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3570)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3617) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:151) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1352) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

При выполнении синхронного `executeSyncWithListener` получаю подвисание интерфейса, что явно не желательно.

**Код фрагмента:**

```
public class MainListFragment extends ListFragment implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    private static final String TAG = "TAG";
    public static final String[] mScope = {VKScope.OFFLINE,VKScope.AUDIO};

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        //set click listener for list
        getListView().setOnItemClickListener(this);

        //login in VK
        VKSdk.login(this, mScope);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, final Intent data){
        if (!VKSdk.isLoggedIn()){}
        else {
            if (!VKSdk.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data, new VKCallback<VKAccessToken>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(VKAccessToken res) {
                   setListAdapter( new SongAdapter(getActivity(), new VKRequestHelper().getMyListMusic()));
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(VKError error) {
                    getActivity().finish();
                }
            })){
                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            }
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Item: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

**Пример метода с класса `VKRequestHelper`:**

```
public class VKRequestHelper {
    private static final String LOG_TAG = "TAG";
    private VKList<VKApiAudio> mVKAnswerSong;
    private ArrayList <Song> mSongList;

    public synchronized ArrayList<Song> getMyListMusic(){
        VKRequest request = VKApi.audio().get();
        request.executeWithListener(new VKRequest.VKRequestListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(VKResponse response) {
                super.onComplete(response);
                mVKAnswerSong = (VKList) response.parsedModel;
                mSongList = new ArrayList<Song>();

                for (int i = 0; i < mVKAnswerSong.size(); i++){
                    mSongList.add(new Song(mVKAnswerSong.get(i)));
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onError(VKError vkError){
                super.onError(vkError);
            }
        });
        return mSongList;
    }
}
```

**UPD2**

*код фрагмента:*

```
public class MainListFragment extends ListFragment implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener, VKRequestHelper.ListMusicLoaded {

    private static final String TAG = "TAG";
    public static final String[] mScope = {VKScope.OFFLINE,VKScope.AUDIO};
    private VKRequestHelper vkRequestHelper;

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        //set click listener for list
        getListView().setOnItemClickListener(this);

        //login in VK
        VKSdk.login(this, mScope);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, final Intent data){
        if (!VKSdk.isLoggedIn()){}
        else {
            if (!VKSdk.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data, new VKCallback<VKAccessToken>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(VKAccessToken res) {
                    vkRequestHelper.getMyListMusic(MainListFragment.this);
                   //setListAdapter( new SongAdapter(getActivity(),new VKRequestHelper().getMyListMusic()));
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(VKError error) {
                    getActivity().finish();
                }
            })){
                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            }
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Item: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onMusicLoaded(ArrayList<Song> list) {
        setListAdapter( new SongAdapter(getActivity(),list));
        Log.d(TAG, list.get(1).getArtist()); //for example
    }

    @Override
        public void onMusicFailed(VKError error) {
            Log.d("TAG", error.errorMessage);
        }
    }
```

*Код класса с запросами:*

```
public class VKRequestHelper {

    private static final String LOG_TAG = "TAG";
    private VKList<VKApiAudio> mVKAnswerSong;
    private ArrayList <Song> mSongList;

    public interface ListMusicLoaded {
        void onMusicLoaded(ArrayList<Song> list);
        void onMusicFailed(VKError error);
    }

    public void getMyListMusic(final ListMusicLoaded listener){
        VKRequest request = VKApi.audio().get();
        request.executeWithListener(new VKRequest.VKRequestListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(VKResponse response) {
                super.onComplete(response);
                mVKAnswerSong = (VKList) response.parsedModel;
                ArrayList<Song> mSongList = new ArrayList<Song>();
                for (int i = 0; i < mVKAnswerSong.size(); i++){
                    mSongList.add(new Song(mVKAnswerSong.get(i)));
                }
                listener.onMusicLoaded(mSongList);
            }
            @Override
            public void onError(VKError vkError){
                super.onError(vkError);
                listener.onMusicFailed(vkError);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Какой смысл возвращать ```mSongList``` из метода, который работает ассинхронно? Как вы думаете в какой момент у вас заполниться ```mSongList```? Скорей всего в этом и ошибка, потому что вы пытаетесь использовать результат работы метода ```getMyListMusic``` сразу после его вызова. Отсюда и NPE у вас в логе.

Comment: Ладно, синхронный запрос. Как тогда быть с подвисанием  интерфейса?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Метод `executeWithListener` работает асинхронно и нет никакого смысла возвращать из метода `getMyListMusic` список `mSongList` т.к. он ещё не будет заполнен и вернется `null`.

В вашем случае можно создать интерфейс который будет выступать в качестве и передать его в метод `getMyListMusic`. Т.е. будет примерное следующее:

```
interface ListMusicLoaded {
    void onMusicLoaded(List<> list);
    void onMusicFailed(VkError error);
}


public void getMyListMusic(ListMusicLoaded listener){
    VKRequest request = VKApi.audio().get();
    request.executeWithListener(new VKRequest.VKRequestListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(VKResponse response) {
            super.onComplete(response);
            mVKAnswerSong = (VKList) response.parsedModel;
            ArrayList<Song> mSongList = new ArrayList<Song>();
            for (int i = 0; i < mVKAnswerSong.size(); i++){
                mSongList.add(new Song(mVKAnswerSong.get(i)));
            }
            listener.onMusicLoaded(mSongList);
        }
        @Override
        public void onError(VKError vkError){
            super.onError(vkError);
            listener.onMusicFailed(vkError);
        }
    });
   }
}
```

Ну а дальше уже в реализации этого листенера делаете то, что вам нужно.

Только вряд ли `VkSdk` как то следит за жизненным циклом, поэтому это вам придется делать самим.

UPD:пример вызова из активити

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity implement ListMusicLoaded {

    private VKRequestHelper vkRequestHelper;

    void loadMusic(){
        vkRequestHelper.getMyListMusic(this);
    }

    void onMusicLoaded(List<> list) {
        //сюда прийдет результат
    }

    void onMusicFailed(VkError error){
        //сюда ошибка
    }
}
```

Необязательно делать `implement ListMusicLoaded`. Можно делать через анонимные классы.

Comment: Не совсем понял зачем нужен интерфейс

Comment: @UjinUkr обновил ответ

Comment: среда ругается на this когда выполняю vkRequestHelper.getMyListMusic(this);  в ActivityResult (код фрагмента)

Comment: @UjinUkr попробуйте ```MainListFragment.this```

Comment: в результате получаю тот же самый NPE (VKRequestHelper.getMyListMusic(com.example.jeka.vkplayer.vkontakte.VKRequestHelper$ListMusicLoaded)' on a null object reference)

Comment: @UjinUkr код покажите

Comment: Смотрите UPD 2.

Comment: @UjinUkr у вас не создан объект ```VKRequestHelper```, отсюда и NPE

Comment: огромное спасибо!!!!)